# Moving object towards certain coordinates and beyond always with the same speed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hello guys I am making a game in python tkinter and where you control a character that is able to shoot where you click. I want the bullet to move towards the point player clicked and beyond always with the same speed using move and after methods and I don't have the knowledge of math to think about an equation that calculates the x and y distances needed to move the bullet towards the point player clicked and beyond till it reaches end of the canvas.  Any ideas? thanks for your time and answer

I already have the player and tkinter class and the method that creates the bullet on click and pass it click coordinates. Now I need to calculate teh change of x and y after one refresh

```
def fly(self):
    self.app.canvsas.move(self.bullet, x and y you calculated)
    self.app.canvas.after(some refresh time, self.fly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to give the bullet a x_speed and y_speed when it is fired and then update each frame by moving the specified amount.  Lets say you click at `(cx,cy)` with the bullet's start location being `(sx,sy)`.  From here you'll want to get the angle made to find `cos(angle)` and `sin(angle)`.  Luckily we can get these without even getting the angle!  With the direct distance from click point and start point `r = ((sx-cx)**2+(sy-cy)**2)**0.5` we will have:

`cos_angle = (cx-sx)/r`

`sin_angle = (cy-sy)/r`

Which can be saved in your bullet instance and multiplied by your bullet's speed to get how far you want to move said bullet in the `x` and `y` direction:

```
def updatebulletbycallingthiseveryframe(self):
    self.x += self.bullet_speed*self.cos_angle
    self.y += self.bullet_speed*self.sin_angle
```

This will keep the bullet moving forever, add a check to see if it is out of bounds and delete the bullet if that happens.

Comment: I tried to implement that and the bullets have different speed, some are slow, some are faster, should I put the same speed to the after method as to the move method or differnet and balance them?

Comment: In your bullet class I would have a variable called `self.bullet_speed` which can be different for each bullet if you want.  If they all have the same speed this method should work fine.  You can have you program print out the values for `cos_angle` and `sin_angle` when the bullet is fired to see if they make sense.